# What is the right way to do facebook login for mobile app (with node.js/passport.js server)

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

I have a mobile app that is working with the backend server, I would like to understand what are the best practices for using facebook to login (create an account) and then to maintain the whole system in sync.

Here is what I understand so far:
- Mobile app can do the login on the device and get the access_token
- Access token can be transferred to the server. I did a proof of concept using passport-facebook-token hooked to some api.myhost.com/auth/facebook route, and it seems I can authenticate the user and retrieve his FB data. Therefore I can either match him to existing user in my database or create a new record.

What I don't understand:
1) Must I use https for transferring the FB token to my server?

2) What do I do for my other requests that are supposed to be authenticated. I don't think going to FB for every request is an option. One option that comes to mind is to generate another (my own) access token and return it as a result of the FB authentication.

The simplest way to do it is by using passport-facebook-token sessions (so that cookie session ID can be serialized and de-serialized into user ID). But that means I need to maintain some KV storage for sessions.

Another way would be generate my own random token for that user, return it along with user ID on successful login, store it in the user record and have each API call from the client provide this id/token pair and revalidate them each time manually without relying on passport. Or then maybe with relying on passport local strategy?

Which one is better? What are pros/cons of each one?

2) If I do plan to use FB token for posting to FB and doing graph analytics (friends etc), I 
am planning to store the token on the server. How often do I need to refresh it? Every time the app starts and refreshes a token on the client should I re-authenticate with my server using new FB token? What about refreshing user FB tokens by server-to-server calls? Should I ever do it if I want to maintain access to user's FB data, but user stopped using my or uses it too infrequently?

Is there anywhere a cookbook of a working scheme that works well?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find anything useful here?

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook token security**

The token that you have created on your mobile app client is for your Facebook app that you have given the ID to in the authentication. I would always use HTTPS when communicating tokens over Internet or any other volatile information.

**Facebook token expiring & refreshing**

When you do the authentication in your mobile app you will often get the token's expiring time in the response with the token. The token expiration is explained in the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension).

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.

About refreshing the token:

> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app, so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background, if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to your app again.